# Problem to install Magento on AWS

Tags: magento-community, aws

I'm trying to install Magento CE 2 on AWS following this tutorial:

https://comtechies.com/how-to-install-magento-on-amazon-ec2.html

However, I cannot go to http://IP/magento. I've look on Google and I saw that my /app/etc/env.php does not exist.

I already tried this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

And I got this error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Locale' not found in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php:64
```

How should I proceed to finish this installation?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide you are referring is about M1. There is one more mandatory step for M2 - launch `composer install` in Magento root directory.

Here is a more relevant guide for M2 - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html

Please note, you need to use real AWS URL instead of `http://127.0.0.1`

Also, M2 has completely different system requirements (php7, mysql,...)

Comment: Hi, I've installed Magento with this tutorial and I've got this message: "[Progress: 441 / 441]
[SUCCESS]: Magento installation complete.
[SUCCESS]: Magento Admin URI: /admin_q1qmij
Nothing to import."

However, I cannot access Magento Admin Page.

Comment: Did you specify the right URL during installation? http://127.0.0.1 from your example will point http request to your local env (not AWS)

Comment: I've specified the url like this: http://<IPv4 Public IP>/magento2/

Comment: What is the error message? You didn't specify the admin URL and Magento generates it for you - admin_q1qmij. Do you use http://x.x.x.x/magento2/index.php/admin_q1qmij url for admin?

Comment: this url http://x.x.x.x/magento2/index.php/admin_q1qmij it's http error 500. and this url http://x.x.x.x/magento2/admin_q1qmij it's not found

Comment: 500 error is too general. I suggest you to enable the developer mode in console by "./bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer" command and uncomment "ini_set('display_errors', 1);" in app/bootstrap.php . After these actions Magento must show more detailed error messages, so we can proceed with debug

Comment: Hi, thanks!!! the problem was permission on folder /magento2/generated! I can log in now, however, the css it's not displayed.

Comment: You said that magento/admin_q1... URL is not working. This might mean that URL rewrite apache feature is not working. You can verify the issue if you check the 404 page(just enter some symbols in URL after "magento"). If the page returns default (non-magento) 404 page - it's the problem in URL rewrites. Then install url rewrites module if you are using apache or use nginx.conf.sample file as a template from Magento directory.

Comment: Hi, the URL is working now. However, I've got an error like this: Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/var/www/html/magento2/var/cache/" is not writable in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209 . I've changed permission and is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to install magento in aws is

**Install same version of php in your localserver**

**Step1.** Install magento in localserver
**Step2.** After that export that database and upload in your aws server
**Step3.** Copy your whole magento files in your local to aws